# is it possible for pnputil to ignore unsigned drivers?

Tags: driver-signing, windows-driver

I've seen lots of question online that are the antonym of this, which is not what I want. I'm using pnputil, with wildcards, to install a driver pack to a machine. I want to enforce digital signatures and not install any unsigned drivers. The command used is,

`pnputil /add-driver c:\Drivers\*.inf /subdirs /install /Reboot`

This works great normally, but when an unsigned driver is reached, a prompt appears saying that the driver is unsigned and halts the process from continuing until the prompt is acknowledge. I'd like to find a way for pnputil to ignore the unsigned driver and move on without a prompt. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use powershell command to check driver signature, check its signed or not. by calling same inf file name means if 1.inf then set it 1.cat to check its signature. or you can simply use following tool. https://github.com/fawazahmed0/windows-unsigned-driver-installer